# Is there a downside to using ".filter().filter().filter()..." in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Are the following two calls resolved to the equivalent SQL query in Django?

Chaining multiple calls

```
Model.objects \
.filter(arg1=foo) \
.filter(arg2=bar) \
...
```

Wrapping all the args together:

```
Model.objects \
.filter(arg1=foo, arg2=bar)
```

I'd like code to be readable (there are MANY more filter calls than I've shown), but only if there's no sacrifice to performance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chaining multiple filter() in Django, is this a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164675/chaining-multiple-filter-in-django-is-this-a-bug)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update:

Disregard this answer. See this better, [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8164920).
Thanks [@Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150999/sam) for the heads up.

### Old Answer:

> Are the following two calls resolved to the equivalent SQL query in Django?

Short answer: yes. They will generate equivalent queries.

I verified this with a model I am using. the queries produced are functionally identical. The different `filter` conditions are `AND`ed together in the query.

> I'd like code to be readable (there are MANY more filter calls than I've shown), but only if there's no sacrifice to performance.

One way to achieve readability is to use a dictionary for collecting all filter conditions. For e.g.

```
conditions = dict(arg1 = foo, arg2 = bar, ....)
conditions.update(argN = baz)

Model.objects.filter(**conditions)
```

Comment: This is not correct for multi-valued relationships. They will generate *different* queries with *different* results given the right conditions. See this answer and the linked documentation - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8164920

Comment: The answer you linked to is both misleading and completely wrong in a major way. The behavior of the two forms is *identical* when no model relationships are involved - both forms AND together the results of the filter parameters. But when doing that across relationships, it can result in an emergent OR behavior, as explained in this *actually* correct answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28253623/10176

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Manoj's answer, here's how you can analyze the sql generated for a `QuerySet` object:

```
result1 = SomeModel.objects.filter(field1=100, field2=200)
print "Result1", results1.query

result2 = SomeModel.objects.filter(field1=100).filter(field2=200)
print "Result2", result2.query
```

Comment: The `assert` statement may not work every time. The order of the `AND` clauses in the generated queries were different when I tried.

Comment: Yup, you're right, just tested it out.  Remove the assert from the answer.