# Chaining multiple filter() in Django, is this a bug?

Tags: django, django-orm

I always assumed that chaining multiple filter() calls in Django was always the same as collecting them in a single call.

```
# Equivalent
Model.objects.filter(foo=1).filter(bar=2)
Model.objects.filter(foo=1,bar=2)
```

but I have run across a complicated queryset in my code where this is not the case

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(auth.models.User)
    vacation = models.BooleanField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)

# Not Equivalent!
Book.objects.filter(inventory__user__profile__vacation=False).filter(inventory__user__profile__country='BR')
Book.objects.filter(inventory__user__profile__vacation=False, inventory__user__profile__country='BR')
```

The generated SQL is

```
SELECT "library_book"."id", "library_book"."asin", "library_book"."added", "library_book"."updated" FROM "library_book" INNER JOIN "library_inventory" ON ("library_book"."id" = "library_inventory"."book_id") INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("library_inventory"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") INNER JOIN "library_profile" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "library_profile"."user_id") INNER JOIN "library_inventory" T5 ON ("library_book"."id" = T5."book_id") INNER JOIN "auth_user" T6 ON (T5."user_id" = T6."id") INNER JOIN "library_profile" T7 ON (T6."id" = T7."user_id") WHERE ("library_profile"."vacation" = False  AND T7."country" = BR )
SELECT "library_book"."id", "library_book"."asin", "library_book"."added", "library_book"."updated" FROM "library_book" INNER JOIN "library_inventory" ON ("library_book"."id" = "library_inventory"."book_id") INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("library_inventory"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") INNER JOIN "library_profile" ON ("auth_user"."id" = "library_profile"."user_id") WHERE ("library_profile"."vacation" = False  AND "library_profile"."country" = BR )
```

The first queryset with the chained `filter()` calls joins the Inventory model twice effectively creating an OR between the two conditions whereas the second queryset ANDs the two conditions together. I was expecting that the first query would also AND the two conditions. Is this the expected behavior or is this a bug in Django?

The answer to a related question [Is there a downside to using ".filter().filter().filter()..." in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733324/is-there-a-downside-to-using-filter-filter-filter-in-django) seems to indicated that the two querysets should be equivalent.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The way I understand it is that they are subtly different by design (and I am certainly open for correction): `filter(A, B)` will first filter according to A and then subfilter according to B, while `filter(A).filter(B)` will return a row that matches A 'and' a potentially different row that matches B.

Look at the example here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships

particularly:

> Everything inside a single filter() call is applied simultaneously to filter out items matching all those requirements. Successive filter() calls further restrict the set of  objects

...

> In this second example (filter(A).filter(B)), the first filter restricted the queryset to (A). The second filter restricted the set of blogs further to those that are also (B). The entries select by the second filter may or may not be the same as the entries in the first filter.`

Comment: Does this mean that the link to the SO question is actually incorrect?

Comment: This behavior, although documented, seems to violate the principle of least astonishment. Multiple filter()'s AND together when fields are on  the same model, but then OR together when spanning relationships.

Comment: I believe you have it the wrong way around in the first paragraph - filter(A, B) is the AND situation ('lennon' AND 2008 in the docs), while filter(A).filter(B) is the OR situation ('lennon' OR 2008). This makes sense when you look at the queries generated in the question - the .filter(A).filter(B) case creates the joins twice, resulting in an OR.

Comment: filter(A, B) is the AND filter(A).filter(B) is OR

Comment: filter(A,B) doesn't work as intended when A and B are [Q() objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#q-objects) containing AND or OR operators.

Comment: so `further restrict` means `less restrictive`?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It is not "OR." This sentence "The second filter restricted the set of blogs further to those that are also (B)." clearly mentions "that are also (B)." If you observe a behavior similar to OR in this specific example, it does not necessarily mean that you can generalize your own interpretation. Please look at the answers by "Kevin 3112" and "Johnny Tsang." I believe those are the correct answers.

Comment: Yep, it is documented in Django. But documenting bad design does not make it good design. There are certain situation where filters appear to be nested. For example, in DRF I add some filtering in `get_queryset(self)` method of a viewset and also use DRF filter backend out of the box. Filters appear to be nested and it works well if applied to the same model, but breaks (as designed) once filtering is done on a related model. It is definitely a violation of principle of least astonishment (at least).

Comment: Django has a built-in Q objects that allows this kind of lookups
Usage : 

`from django.db.models import Q 

Item.objects.filter(Q(A),Q(B));  // A Or B 
Item.objects.filter(A,B); // A AND B `

Comment: @anouares-sayid I believe you are mistaken, `Q(A) | Q(B)` means OR.

Comment: They're both ANDs, just applied in different places. The chained version filters books linked to a profile that has vacation=False AND linked to a profile that has country='BR'.  The single filter version filters books linked to a profile that has vacation=False AND country='BR'.

Comment: This answer is not correct, it depends if the target fields in the filters are relationships or not !!

Answer (score 110):

These two style of filtering are equivalent in most cases, but when query on objects base on ForeignKey or ManyToManyField, they are slightly different.

Examples from [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships).

**model**
Blog to Entry is a one-to-many relation.

```
from django.db import models

class Blog(models.Model):
    ...

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    ...
```

**objects**
Assuming there are some blog and entry objects here.
[image]

**queries**

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline_contains='Lennon', 
    entry__pub_date__year=2008)
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline_contains='Lennon').filter(
    entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

For the 1st query (single filter one), it match only blog1.

For the 2nd query (chained filters one), it filters out blog1 and blog2.
The first filter restricts the queryset to blog1, blog2 and blog5; the second filter restricts the set of blogs further to blog1 and blog2.

And you should realize that

> **We are filtering the Blog items with each filter statement, not the Entry items.**

So, it's not the same, because Blog and Entry are multi-valued relationships.

Reference:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships
If there is something wrong, please correct me.

Edit: Changed v1.6 to v1.8 since the 1.6 links are no longer available.

Comment: You seem to be mixed up between  "matches" and "filters out". If you stuck to "this query returns" it would be a lot clearer.

Comment: Very good schematic example which is clarifying the difference betweent the two.

Answer (score 10):

As you can see in the generated SQL statements the difference is not the "OR" as some may suspect. It is how the WHERE and JOIN is placed.

### Example1 (same joined table)  :

(example from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon', entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

This will give you all the Blogs that have **one** entry with both (entry_*headline*_contains='Lennon') AND (entry__pub_date__year=2008), which is what you would expect from this query.
Result:
Book with {entry.headline: 'Life of Lennon', entry.pub_date: '2008'}

### Example 2 (chained)

```
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon').filter(entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

This will cover all the results from Example 1, but it will generate slightly more result. Because it first filters all the blogs with (entry_*headline*_contains='Lennon') and then from the result filters (entry__pub_date__year=2008).

The difference is that it will also give you results like:
Book with {entry.headline: '**Lennon**', entry.pub_date: 2000}, {entry.headline: 'Bill', entry.pub_date: **2008**}

### In your case

I think it is this one you need:

```
Book.objects.filter(inventory__user__profile__vacation=False, inventory__user__profile__country='BR')
```

And if you want to use OR please read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: The second example isn't actually true. All the chained filters are applied to the queried objects, i.e. they are ANDed together in the query.

Comment: I believe that Example 2 is correct, and it is actually a explanation taken from the official Django documents, as referenced. I might not be the best explainer and I pardon for that. Example 1 is a direct AND as you would expect in a normal SQL writing.

Example 1 gives something like this: 
'SELECT blog JOIN entry WHERE entry.head_line LIKE "*Lennon*" AND entry.year == 2008

Example 2 gives something like this:
'SELECT blog JOIN entry WHERE entry.head_list LIKE "*Lennon*" 
UNION
SELECT blog JOIN entry WHERE entry.head_list LIKE "*Lennon*"'

Comment: Sir, you are quite right. In a hurry I missed the fact that our filtering criteria is pointing to a one-to-many relation, not to the blog itself.

Answer (score 10):

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) :

> To handle both of these situations, Django has a consistent way of processing filter() calls. Everything inside a single filter() call is applied simultaneously to filter out items matching all those requirements. Successive filter() calls further restrict the set of objects, but for multi-valued relations, they apply to any object linked to the primary model, not necessarily those objects that were selected by an earlier filter() call.

- It is clearly said that multiple conditions in a single `filter()` are applied simultaneously.
  That means that doing :

```py
objs = Mymodel.objects.filter(a=True, b=False)
```

will return a queryset with raws from model `Mymodel` where `a=True` **AND** `b=False`.

- Successive `filter()`, in some case, will provide the same result. Doing :

```py
objs = Mymodel.objects.filter(a=True).filter(b=False)
```

will return a queryset with raws from model `Mymodel` where `a=True` **AND** `b=False` too. Since you obtain "first" a queryset with records which have `a=True` and then it's restricted to those who have `b=False` at the same time.

- The difference in chaining `filter()` comes when there are `multi-valued relations`, which means you are going through other models (such as the example given in the docs, between Blog and Entry models). It is said that in that case `(...) they apply to any object linked to the primary model, not necessarily those objects that were selected by an earlier filter() call.`

Which means that it applies the successives `filter()` on the target model directly, not on previous `filter()`

If I take the example from the docs :

```py
Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon').filter(entry__pub_date__year=2008)
```

remember that it's the model `Blog` that is filtered, not the `Entry`. So it will treat the 2 `filter()` independently.

It will, for instance, return a queryset with Blogs, that have entries that contain 'Lennon' (even if they are not from 2008) and entries that are from 2008 (even if their headline does not contain 'Lennon')

[THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65065813/12085129) goes even further in the explanation. And the original question is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you don't want to join multiple filters together like this:

```
def your_dynamic_query_generator(self, event: Event):
    qs \
    .filter(shiftregistrations__event=event) \
    .filter(shiftregistrations__shifts=False)
```

And the following code would actually not return the correct thing.

```
def your_dynamic_query_generator(self, event: Event):
    return Q(shiftregistrations__event=event) & Q(shiftregistrations__shifts=False)
```

What you can do now is to use an annotation count-filter.

In this case we count all shifts which belongs to a certain event.

```
qs: EventQuerySet = qs.annotate(
    num_shifts=Count('shiftregistrations__shifts', filter=Q(shiftregistrations__event=event))
)
```

Afterwards you can filter by annotation.

```
def your_dynamic_query_generator(self):
    return Q(num_shifts=0)
```

This solution is also cheaper on large querysets.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

Saw this in a comment and I thought it was the simplest explanation.

filter(A, B) is the AND ; filter(A).filter(B) is OR

It's true if every linked model satisfies both conditions

Comment: @lbris is this *ever* true?

Comment: It's true if every linked model satisfies both conditions ;)