# how to pull value from queryset by going to database once django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a function that sets up the data for another method.  It does this to limit calls to the database.

The setup method looks like so:

```
def get_customers(request):
    customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(pk=request.user)

    populated_customer = get_customer(request, customer_list)
```

The method that does the processing looks like this:

```
def get_customer(request):
    for customer in customer_list:
         if customer.id == 3:
              # do something with this customer
```

Instead of doing the for loop to find the customer I need, how can I pull it out of the list without going to the database because I am dealing with millions of records.

Comment: Why do you need to keep `customer_list` if, according to the `get_customer` view, you need only one customer - why don't just filter the customer by primary key from the database? Also, you may start caching customers in key:value stores like memcached or redis.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are doing here is pulling all the users records into python (django) memory, then filtering them out by looping through this QuerySet.

A better approach might be chaining these Queries to your database, which is supported by the django [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) language.

It would be wise to look at the documentation concerning [chained filter methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships), but a sample query might look like this:

```
customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(pk=request.user).filter(id=3)
```

[As shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164675/chaining-multiple-filter-in-django-is-this-a-bug), this is not the same as the following:

```
customer_list = Customer.objects.filter(pk=request.user,id=3)
```