# django filtering on a dynamic queryset with twice the same object

Tags: django, dynamic, filtering, django-queryset

I am trying to filter by the `com_proc` variable but it does not work...
The complexity here is that the **filter can contain** **more than once the same object**. Here is my code:

```
class Act(models.Model):
    com_proc=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    cs_1=models.ForeignKey(CodeSect, related_name='code_sect_1', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    cs_2=models.ForeignKey(CodeSect, related_name='code_sect_2', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    cs_3=models.ForeignKey(CodeSect, related_name='code_sect_3', blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class ActIds(models.Model):
    propos_origine=models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    act=models.ForeignKey(Act)


qs_acts=ActIds.objects.none()
len(qs_acts)
for act in ActIds.objects.all():
    #loop over each cs variable
    for nb in range(1,4):
        code_sect=getattr(act.act, "cs_"+str(nb))
        if code_sect is not None:
            qs_acts._result_cache.append(act)
print "qs_acts"
for act in qs_acts:
    print act.pk, act.act.com_proc, act.propos_origine
```

I use a dynamic `queryset` with `_result_cache` because each object can be present in the filter up to three times (once for each `cs` variable). I don't know how to reproduce that with a normal filtering.

Output:

```
9429 Oral procedure COM
9429 Oral procedure COM
9697 Written procedure COM
12352 Written procedure COM
12362 Oral procedure COM
```

Code:

```
...
print filter_vars_periods
```

Output:

```
{'act__com_proc': 'Written procedure', 'propos_origine': 'COM', 'act__adopt_conseil__gte': datetime.date(2009, 12, 1), 'act__adopt_conseil__lte': datetime.date(2013, 12, 31)}
```

Code:

```
temp_filter=qs_acts.filter(**filter_vars_periods)
for act in temp_filter:
    print act.pk, act.act.com_proc, act.propos_origine
```

Output:

```
9429 Oral procedure COM
9429 Oral procedure COM
9697 Written procedure COM
12352 Written procedure COM
12362 Oral procedure COM
```

You can see that the filtering by the `com_proc="Written procedure"` did not work, I get the same queryset at the end. Why?

### Edit

I think I know why two successive filterings do not give the expected output:
[Chaining multiple filter() in Django, is this a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164675/chaining-multiple-filter-in-django-is-this-a-bug/8164920#8164920)
It is said that using two filters is not the equivalent of the logical `AND` but is the equivalent of the logical `OR`. So that could be the reason why my second filter doesn't filter anything...
Anyway, I still don't know how to solve my problem :(.

Comment: The chained multiple filter link you added is not related to your issue. That functionality only comes into play when you're traversing a 1 to many relationship (or many to many). If you were trying to fetch Acts based on properties of ActId's then it would be of a concern to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's **not possible to use a queryset storing more than once the same object.**
Instead, I use a **list**:

```
class Act(models.Model):
    com_proc=models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    cs_1=models.ForeignKey(CodeSect, related_name='code_sect_1', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    cs_2=models.ForeignKey(CodeSect, related_name='code_sect_2', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    cs_3=models.ForeignKey(CodeSect, related_name='code_sect_3', blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class ActIds(models.Model):
    propos_origine=models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    act=models.ForeignKey(Act)


qs_acts=[]
for act in ActIds.objects.all():
    #loop over each cs variable
    for nb in range(1,4):
        code_sect=getattr(act.act, "cs_"+str(nb))
        if code_sect is not None:
            qs_acts.append(act)
```

Then the problem is that I cannot do the following anymore:

```
temp_filter=qs_acts.filter(**filter_vars).exclude(**exclude_vars)
```

Instead I created a function to translate django syntax:

```
def filter_exclude_list(list_acts, filter_vars={}, exclude_vars={}):
    list_acts_new=[]
    for act in list_acts:
        ok=True
        for key, value in filter_vars.iteritems():
            #related object: "act__validated_attendance":1
            if key[:5]=="act__":
                key=key[5:]
                instance=act.act
            else:
                instance=act
            #greater than or equal: "nb_point_a__gte": 1
            if key[-5:]=="__gte":
                if getattr(instance, key[:-5])<value:
                    ok=False
                    break
            #"com_amdt_tabled__isnull": False
            elif key[-8:]=="__isnull":
                if getattr(instance, key[:-8]) is None:
                    ok=False
                    break
            #equal to: "nb_point_a": 1
            elif getattr(instance, key) != value:
                ok=False
                break

        if ok:
            for key, value in exclude_vars.iteritems():
                #"adopt_cs_abs": None
                if key=="adopt_cs_abs" and value is None:
                    if not getattr(instance, key).exists():
                        ok=False
                        break
                #different from: "nb_point_a": 1
                elif getattr(instance, key) == value:
                    ok=False
                    break

            if ok:
                list_acts_new.append(act)

    return list_acts_new
```

Then I can do:

```
qs_acts_new=filter_exclude_list(qs_acts, filter_vars=filter_vars, exclude_vars=exclude_vars)
```

This works, but I am posting this hoping that someone has a better and more concise solution :).