# Filter queryset by optional start and end date

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-1.10

I want to filter a queryset by a date range where both the start and end date are optional. Specifically,

```
if dt_from:
    results = results.filter(date_modified__gte=dt_from)
if dt_until:
    results = results.filter(date_modified__lte=dt_until)
```

where `dt_from` and `dt_until` are each either `datetime.datetime`, `datetime.date`, or `None`. The documentation about the behaviour of chaining multiple filters is extremely confusing however (see [Chaining multiple filter() in Django, is this a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164675/chaining-multiple-filter-in-django-is-this-a-bug)), and I'm not sure that the above does what I think it does (it may OR the filters rather than ANDing them).

Does the above code achieve what I want (i.e. AND the two filters) or is there another way I should do this?

Comment: If you go with this approach, don't forget to update the `results` variable: `results = results.filter(date_modified__gte=dt_from)` and `results = results.filter(date_modified__lte=dt_until)`.

Comment: @alecxe right, thanks :)

Comment: That linked question is not at all relevant, since it refers to queries across relationships. The docs are quite clear here (and indeed are referenced in that accepted answer): "Successive filter() calls further restrict the set of objects".

Answer (score 1):

I have a generic solution for this kind of problems.  Reuse this [custom queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#create-manager-with-queryset-methods) for all models

```
class MyQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def filter_if(self, **kwargs):
        new_kwargs = {a: b for (a, b) in kwargs.items() if b}
        return self.filter(new_kwargs)

results.filter_if(date_modified__gte=dt_from, date_modified__lte=dt_until)
```