# Django - Accessing sublist of list in for loop

Tags: python, django

I have a query that outputs data in the following format:

```
[["W/E 6/11/17", "Carter, J", 40.0],
 ["W/E 6/18/17", "Carter, J", 40.0],
 ["W/E 6/11/17", "Linn, K", 27.0],
 ["W/E 6/18/17", "Linn, K", 27.0],
 ["W/E 6/11/17", "Massey, S", 55.0],
 ["W/E 6/18/17", "Massey, S", 45.0]]
```

My query:

```
emp3 = (
    Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.values(
        'employeename', 'displayval')
    .order_by()
    .filter(businessunit='a')
    .filter(billinggroup__startswith='PLS - Pip')
    .filter(Q(displayval=sunday2)|Q(displayval=sunday))
    .annotate(plannedhours__sum=Sum('plannedhours'))
)
```

In my template, I'm currently using a for loop, but it returns all items in the list, rather than just the first list of lists.

```
{% for x in emp3 %}
{{x.employeename}}
{{x.plannedhours__sum}}
```

What I would like to do is iterate through the list and display Employee: Value for W/E 6/11, Value for W/E 6/18 in a horizontal form.

Model:

```
class Projectsummaryplannedhours(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(db_column='Number', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    description = models.CharField(db_column='Description', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    clientname = models.CharField(db_column='ClientName', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    department = models.CharField(db_column='Department', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    billinggroup = models.CharField(db_column='BillingGroup', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    businessunit = models.CharField(db_column='BusinessUnit', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    employeename = models.CharField(db_column='EmployeeName', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    displayval = models.CharField(db_column='DisplayVal', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    startofweek = models.DateTimeField(db_column='StartOfWeek', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    endofweek = models.DateTimeField(db_column='EndOfWeek', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    plannedhours = models.DecimalField(db_column='PlannedHours', max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    rateschedule = models.CharField(db_column='RateSchedule', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    classification = models.CharField(db_column='Classification', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dollarsforecast = models.DecimalField(db_column='DollarsForecast', max_digits=10, decimal_places=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    deleted = models.NullBooleanField(db_column='Deleted')  # Field name made lowercase.
    datelastmodified = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateLastModified', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DateCreated', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
```

**Updated Query:**

```
emp3_list = Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.values('employeename', 'displayval').order_by().filter(businessunit='a').filter(billinggroup__startswith='PLS - Pip').filter(Q(displayval=sunday2)|Q(displayval=sunday)).annotate(plannedhours__sum=Sum('plannedhours'))
emp3 = map(lambda x: {'date': x[0], 'employee_name': x[1], 'planned_hours': x[2]}, emp3_list)
```

Every query I have tried:

```
def DesignHubR(request):
#emp1 = Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.filter(employeename__startswith='Linn').values_list('endofweek').annotate(plannedhours__sum=Sum('plannedhours'))

day = datetime.datetime.today()
start = day - timedelta(days=day.weekday())
s1 = start + timedelta(days=6)
day2 = day + + timedelta(days=7)
start2 = day2 - timedelta(days=day.weekday())
s2 = start2 + timedelta(days=6)
sunday = datetime.datetime.strftime(s1, "W/E %#m/%#d/%y")
sunday2 = datetime.datetime.strftime(s2, "W/E %#m/%#d/%y")
employee = Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.order_by().values_list('employeename', flat=True).distinct().filter(businessunit='a').filter(billinggroup__startswith='PLS - Pip')
emp1 = Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.values_list('displayval', 'employeename').filter(businessunit='a').filter(billinggroup__startswith='PLS - Pip').filter(displayval=sunday).annotate(plannedhours__sum=Sum('plannedhours'))
emp4 = Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.filter(employeename__startswith='Linn').filter(Q(displayval=sunday2)|Q(displayval=sunday)).annotate(plannedhours__sum=Sum('plannedhours'))
emp2 = Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.values_list('displayval', 'employeename').filter(businessunit='a').filter(billinggroup__startswith='PLS - Pip').filter(Q(displayval=sunday2)|Q(displayval=sunday)).annotate(plannedhours__sum=Sum('plannedhours'))
emp3_list = Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.values_list('displayval', 'employeename').filter(businessunit='a').filter(billinggroup__startswith='PLS - Pip').filter(Q(displayval=sunday2)|Q(displayval=sunday)).annotate(plannedhours__sum=Sum('plannedhours'))
emp3 = map(lambda x: {'date': x[0], 'employee_name': x[1], 'planned_hours': x[2]}, emp3_list)
context = {'emp1': emp1, 'emp2': emp2, 'sunday2': sunday2, 'employee': employee, 'emp3': emp3, 'emp4': emp4}
return render(request,'department_hub_ple.html', context)
```

Comment: how are you sending your list to the template context?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want. Is the query output correct or is it the part you'd like to get right?

Comment: context = {'emp3': emp3} then rendering context

Comment: @Jérôme the query output is correct unless I need another output to get the desired result in my template. I just posted the query output so the data I'm outputting would be clear.

Comment: Note that calling `filter()` multiple times ends up filtering for objects that match one or more of the criteria. Is that what you're expecting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164675/chaining-multiple-filter-in-django-is-this-a-bug

Comment: @Nathan Jones the data is returning what I expected it to return with those filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list indexes in the following way:

```
{{ x.0 }}
```

So your template might look like (without any markup or styling):

```
{% for x in emp3 %}
  {{ x.1 }}
  {{ x.2 }}
{% endfor %}
```

See [Docs on Variables and Lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups)

### EDIT

If you're looking for a way to use only the list in your list-of-lists, you can chain lookups. The following example would give the second element of the first list.

```
{{ x.0.1 }}
```

This probably makes your template harder to read, since it's not very clear what `x.0.1` refers to in your context. You might consider changing the data structure of the results, and limiting the data your view returns to just the data your template is going to use.

### EDIT 2

To make your template more readable, use a `map` function convert your list-of-lists back to a list-of-dicts:

```
emp3_list = [
    ["W/E 6/11/17", "Carter, Jon", 40.0],
    ["W/E 6/18/17", "Carter, Jon", 40.0],
    ["W/E 6/11/17", "Linn, Kenneth", 27.0],
    ["W/E 6/18/17", "Linn, Kenneth", 27.0],
    ["W/E 6/11/17", "Massey, Smiley", 55.0],
    ["W/E 6/18/17", "Massey, Smiley", 45.0]
]
emp3 = map(lambda x: {'date': x[0], 'employee_name': x[1], 'planned_hours': x[2]}, emp3_list)
```

Your template would then look like this:

```
{% for x in emp3 %}
    Employee: {{ x.employee_name }}
    Date: {{ x.date }}
    Planned Hours: {{ x.planned_hours }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: x.0, x.1 doesn't work with .values, only values_list. I have tried using a values list but it's returning both lists, and I want to define it to return only one list.

Comment: As the docs state, the template engine tries to interpret `x.0` in three different ways: by `dict` key lookup, then `attribute` lookup, then `list`-index. You're right that it won't work for `.values()` because it returns a list of `dict`s. However, that doesn't mean this syntax won't work with list-indexes too. Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I have tried using values_list and values. When using values_list I can use the .0, .1, etc it returns all values for that variable. So I have [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]. Using x.0 returns 1,4. I would like to return just 1 or just 4.

Comment: Edited to address your comment.

Comment: I see what you mean. So {{x.0.1}} does not work inside a for loop. It's just calling individual parts of the list.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're after. Do you only want to use the first list in your list-of-lists, or do want to do something with all of your lists? The first example works within a for loop, the second one doesn't.

Comment: So in my database I have a row for every hour planned to a project, by week. I want to sum the hours by week, by employee and have those listed out for each employee.

Comment: I've also hit issues where I receive this error "invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." when attempting to a variable call in my template.

Comment: Could you post your `Projectsummaryplannedhours` model code? We could probably make your `annotate()` code return a list of dicts, which will make the template code more readable in the end.

Comment: Nathan, thanks again for your help - I have been obsessing over this issue for 2 days... I added the model to the OP.

Comment: Nathan, thanks for your update. I am receiving a key error when I attempt to map a list-of-dicts

Comment: What is the error you get, and could you edit your question to include the code you have?

Comment: Check bottom of OP for updated query. I'm receiving the following error:       Exception Type: KeyError at /app/designhubr/
Exception Value: 0

Comment: Are you sure `emp3_list` is still a list-of-lists? If not, please post what `emp3_list`'s value is before the `map()` tries to run.

Comment: I changed it back to a values_list and lost the error. I'm getting my data in the same format as I have been though. I want to display my hours by employee in a row, where the columns are hours by week, rather than vertically. Vertically i get duplicate employee names. Maybe I've done a bad job of explaining myself.

Comment: Oh, you want it grouped by employee. Use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group by employee name. I'm a bit busy at the moment, but I could provide an example later today if you're still struggling.

Comment: Thanks for all your help nathan. I've updated the OP with all the variations of queries I have in my view.

Comment: Nathan, I got it. I think this puts me on the path I need to be on. Thanks so much.

Comment: I marked it as answered but my answers aren't registering publicly because of my reputation level. I have another issue I'll need a bit of guidance on (nesting another for statement within the for statement we just created, while getting the employee_name from the above query. I could venmo you some $ for the help.

Comment: I really appreciate the monetary offer, but that's not necessary :)

Comment: Could you possibly take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509521/nested-regroups-django ?

Comment: I'm thinking a nested regroup might not be possible for what I want to achieve. I am thinking iterating over the query and adding 0 planned hours for employees if they don't have any might be the best route.