# Nested Regroups - Django

Tags: python, django

I have a model with the following fields: "Date", "Employee", and "Planned Hours". Each employee has various planned hours for various dates.

I'm attempting to structure my template where employees are listed in rows and their planned hours are listed in columns under the correct corresponding date.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX2WK.png)

My template looks like this so far:

```
{% regroup emp3 by employee_name as emp9 %}
{% for employee_name in emp9 %}
<!--Job-->
<div class="table-row table-job-column employee-row"{{employee_name.grouper}}</div>

{% for x in employee_name.list %}

<div class="table-row table-fr-column">{{x.planned_hours}}</div>

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

My view:

```
def DesignHubR(request):
emp3_list = Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.values_list('displayval', 'employeename').filter(businessunit='a').filter(billinggroup__startswith='PLS - Project').filter(Q(displayval=sunday2)|Q(displayval=sunday)).annotate(plannedhours__sum=Sum('plannedhours'))
emp3 = map(lambda x: {'date': x[0], 'employee_name': x[1], 'planned_hours': x[2]}, emp3_list)
context = {'sunday': sunday, 'sunday2': sunday2, 'emp3': emp3}
return render(request,'department_hub_ple.html', context)
```

My issue with the current structure is it places the first "planned hour" next to the employee. I need to be able to insert a blank column if there are no planned hours for that date. I realize I haven't included a nested regroup, but everything I've tried hasn't worked.

Note: I'm pulling my column dates in outside the regroup.

EDIT TO INCLUDE EMP3_LIST:

```
[{'date': 'W/E 6/18/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('45.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Bob'}, {'date': 'W/E 6/25/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('45.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Bob'}, {'date': 'W/E 6/18/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('17.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Jack'}, {'date': 'W/E 6/25/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('13.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Jack'}, {'date': 'W/E 6/25/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('1.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Stan'}, {'date': 'W/E 6/18/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('27.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Albert'}, {'date': 'W/E 6/25/17', 'planned_hours': Decimal('29.00000'), 'employee_name': 'Albert'}]
```

Edit 2:

```
{% regroup emp3 by employee_name as emp9 %}
{% for employee_name in emp9 %}
<!--Job-->
<div class="table-row table-job-column employee-row">
{{employee_name.grouper}}</div>
{% regroup employee_name.list by date as date_list %}
{% for x in date_list %}
{% regroup x.list by planned_hours as plan_list %}
{% for y in plan_list %}

<div class="table-row table-fr-column">{{y.grouper}}</div>

{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are you saying that when an employee has no planned hours for a day that you want that cell to be blank for that employee on that day? But that right now it disregards days with no planned hours and shifts planned hours from future days to the left?

Comment: That's exactly correct. The way it's setup now it just starts at the beginning of the list and spits out planned hours by employee.

Comment: So the data you send in `employee_name.list` will need to have some sort of item for each day, even if there are no planned hours for that day. So say you have a list of dictionaries like: [ {'planned_hours': 3}, {'planned_hours': 6}, {'planned_hours': 1} ]. If there is a day between (or before) those then you need to have {'planned_hours': 0} or something like that. You'll want to account for each day or else everything will shift left. Does that make sense? Is that the problem or is it something else?

Comment: That makes sense, but I thought this was achievable with a nested regroup. I added my view to the OP. Not sure how I would structure a function to add in "0" values into the list.

Comment: Thanks for including your view. I think your `grouper` is only grouping list items by employee name. I'd be interested to see an example of your `emp3_list`. If each each employee does not have all of the days as the other employees then there will be columns that don't line up. If you didn't have multiple employees on the same table this would not be an issue. I think it's best to have all of your days defined as columns whether or not all employees have `planned_hours` on those days.

Comment: I've added emp3_list to show you how it pulls in. Each employee will not have the same days. And my current list is actually a small sample of what will be included. Is there a way I could create a function to insert 0 hours if a date exists but planned hours don't exist for an employee?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to regroup your regroup? Also have you tried ClassBased Views at all? They are really useful for quick code generation. Something like the following.

The View:

```
Class EmployeeTimeSheetView(ListView):
    model = Projectsummaryplannedhours
    template_name = "department_hub_ple.html"

    def get_queryset(self): 
       return Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.all().order_by('-date')
```

The Template:

```
{% regroup object_list by date|date:"m/d/Y" as date_list %}
    {% for date in date_list %}
     ###html code {{ date.grouper }}
    {% regroup date.list by employee as employee_list %}
        {% for employee in employee_list %}
            ###html code {{ employee.grouper }}
        {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
```

This should allow you to build a table with dates as the column headers and then list the employees in oder below with their planned hours. It might require a little tweaking to get it to display the information you want and that might just comedown to which fields you regroup by.

I use this kind of regroup to group related items by Month then by Week.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was AFK when you responded in the IRC chat. I've attempted the nested regroup, but get the same results with the code i implemented in "Edit 2". One problem is my "date" is actually a string, not a date.

Comment: Is there reason why this can't be changed to a datefield over a string?

**EDIT**
Convert your string into a date object.

from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Jun 1 2005  1:33PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')

Comment: Well, i guess my point is it doesn't really matter. I am using a date now, and i have the same issue. When I call {{date.grouper}} I get my dates listed more than once.

Comment: I think if I wanted to have a row for every date per employee it would line up, but it wouldn't be congruent across all dates.