# Django - Iterate over queryset and add static values

Tags: python, django

In the following queryset I am filtering planned hours per week (displayval is my week in this queryset) by employee. I would like to add an item for planned hours = 0 when the employee has no hours planned for a week I'm filtering by.

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

```
def DesignHubR(request):
        emp3_list = Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.values_list('displayval', 'employeename')
                .filter(businessunit='a')
                .filter(billinggroup__startswith='PLS - Project')
                .filter(Q(displayval=sunday2)|Q(displayval=sunday))
                .annotate(plannedhours__sum=Sum('plannedhours'))
        emp3 = map(lambda x: {'date': x[0], 'employee_name': x[1], 'planned_hours': x[2]}, emp3_list)
        context = {'sunday': sunday, 'sunday2': sunday2, 'emp3': emp3}
        return render(request,'department_hub_ple.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use the `Coalesce(*expressions, **extra)` function to solve your problem.

> Accepts a list of at least two field names or expressions and returns the first non-null value (note that an empty string is not considered a null value).

So your query will be looking like:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
emp3_list = \
    Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.\
            filter(
                Q(businessunit='a') &
                Q(billinggroup__startswith='PLS - Project') &
                (Q(displayval=sunday2) | Q(displayval=sunday))
            ).\
            annotate(plannedhours__sum=Coalesce(
                        Sum('plannedhours'), Value(0)
                    )
            ).\
            values_list('displayval', 'employeename')
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce for more information.

This will help you to get `plannedhours__sum = 0` if no entries to sum exists. If you also want to add additional parameter to each entry where `plannedhours__sum = 0` you can use Django conditional expression.Read about Case expression for more information (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case).

> Case() accepts any number of When() objects as individual arguments. Other options are provided using keyword arguments. If none of the conditions evaluate to TRUE, then the expression given with the default keyword argument is returned. If a default argument isn’t provided, None is used.

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
emp3_list = \
    Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.\
        filter(
            Q(businessunit='a') &
            Q(billinggroup__startswith='PLS - Project') &
            (Q(displayval=sunday2) | Q(displayval=sunday))
        ).\
        annotate(plannedhours__sum=Coalesce(
                    Sum('plannedhours'), Value(0)
                ),
                x=Case(When(plannedhours__sum=0, then=Value(0)),
                output_field=IntegerField())
        ).\
        values_list('displayval', 'employeename')
```

This will give you additional parameter x equals 0 if planned hours = 0 and None elsewhere. You can also filter `emp3_list` by annotated values.

As a result you can pass your queryset to a template `context = {'sunday': sunday, 'sunday2': sunday2, 'emp3': emp3_list}`, iterate over it there and get the attributes you need:

```
for q in emp3_list:
    print(q[0], q[1], q[2])
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My planned_hours is a decimal field so I used that and i get this error: "Unsupported lookup 'sum' for DecimalField or join on the field not permitted."

Comment: What if you try to change IntegerField() for a DecimalField() and also change  Sum('plannedhours') to a Sum(F('palannedhours'))?

Comment: I get the same error regardless if I use output_field=IntegerField() or output_field=DecimalField()

Comment: That's odd. I'm trying to annotate Sum() over a DecimalField and it works correctly. My example is `decimal_sum = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)` as a model field and `Event.objects.annotate(a__sum=Coalesce(Sum('decimal_sum'), Value(0))).values_list('id')` as a query.

Comment: In other query's i'm using aggregate sum and coalesce. And in this query i'm already summing with annotate.

Comment: Am I understand you in a proper way: do you need to add additional field to your entry if 'plannedhours' equals 0?

Comment: No, if planned_hours does not exist for a date and employee, then I need an additional planned hours = 0 for that date and employee

Comment: Can you try one more solution? `Projectsummaryplannedhours.objects.filter(...).annotate(plannedhours__sum=Case(When(plannedhours=None, then=Value(0)), default=F('plannedhours'), output_field=DecimalField())).values_list('displayval', 'employeename', 'plannedhours__sum')` In this case you no need to get plannedhours anymore. If one exists its value will be passed to a `plannedhours__sum` elsewhere `plannedhours__sum` will be equal to zero.

Comment: A. Grinenko, thank you for taking the time to help me. When I implemented this query I lost the group by sum on "displayval" which is my date. It also did not generate zero planned hours for items with no hours. I have been attempting this route because I have unable to solve my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44509521/nested-regroups-django